PHPMailer not working after update to version 6
Been running along just fine with Version: 5.2.6 of PHPMailer on PHP7, but every once in a while the emails fail to go.  So, I decided to update PHPMailer to Version 6. Not using the composer so basically all I've done is upload the src directory to my website and add the following lines to my script:
require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'src/SMTP.php';
It never goes past this line:
$mail = new PHPMailer();
Am I missing something?  I've looked at a number of threads over the last few hours, but can't seem to get anything to work.
Copied the src directory from the zip file that I downloaded.  Added the following lines to my script:
require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'src/SMTP.php';
The script never gets past this line:
$mail = new PHPMailer();
I get no errors and debug is set to 2.  All I get is a blank screen.

Did the docs on upgrading not help? Did you look in your web server's error log?

Also read this Q&A

Took another in-depth look at the the docs, as mentioned.  The web server logs told me nothing. What I did read was that these lines, especially the first two, should be at the top of the script and not inside a function.  So, since I'm using a Class file for messaging, I added these lines just inside the Class definition.
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'src/Exception.php';
require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'src/SMTP.php';

